# How to call a Dialogue box from Menu using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, dialog

I want to Make a Help Dialogue Box. When we Press Help Menu then Dialogue box will appear.
Current code is

```
 h_opt3 = uimenu('Label','&Help');
uimenu(h_opt3,'Label','How to Use','Callback','dialog','separator','on');
```

It only show empty dialog.

In place of **dialog** i want to put a dialogbox which will describe how to use my software. 
How to code this all. Please help.

**Requirements:** How to Add stuff in DialogBox and how to call it in above mention scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing an additional callback function, and look at helpdlg instead of dialog.

I can't test any code now, but something like the following should work.

```
function help_callback
    h = helpdlg('Directions','title');
end
```

Then change your uimenu call to this code

```
uimenu(h_opt3,'Label','How to Use','Callback',@help_callback,'separator','on');
```

Comment: function call should be as @help_callback. 
Thanks

Comment: thank you, @AdnanAli. I changed the response to correct my error.